# Windows Scaling in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, scaling

Is there any way to change windows scaling in Ubuntu 17.10 just like in the other versions? May be a terminal command?

Comment: The "duplicate answer" is no duplicate answer because it does not answer how to achieve this on a stock Ubuntu 17.10 and honestly, it can't be the solution to have to install additional software or use the command line to change the display scaling on the newest Ubuntu release. C'mon, we have 2017!